# How to correct a T-SQL syntax error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to do a calculated column using SQL Server 2008 but get a syntax error near `>`:

```
Select
   *, 
   AverageCost = case Quantity 
                    when > 0 then (TotalCost / Quantity) 
                    else null 
                 end 
from ProductTable;
```

Could someone with sharper eyes tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Quantity must be after the then

```
Select *, AverageCost = 
case when Quantity > 0 then (TotalCost / Quantity) else null end from ProductTable;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Will accept as answer when time lock allows.